# How to configure Spring Boot OAuth2.0 server with custom UserDetailsService and password validation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to configure a Spring Boot OAuth2.0 server on my existing schema. To authenticate a user with my schema, I need to retrieve an encrypted password from my `users` table and pass it to an external service for validation.

I was able to define a custom `UserDetailsService` as below, but the default behavior authenticates based on a comparison of the password in the returned `UserDetails` object and the password from the request.

How can I customize this behavior so that I can use my custom `UserDetailsService`, but offload the password validation to the external service?

```
@Component("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String login) {

        String sql = "select encrypted_password from users where login_name = ?";
        String encryptedPassword = null;
        try {
            Connection con = dataSource.getConnection(); 
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql));
            statement.setString(1, login);

            try (ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery()) {
                if (results.next()) {
                    encryptedPassword = results.getLong("encrypted_password");
                }

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return new User(login, encryptedPassword, Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("simpleAuth")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I probably don't have enough details to go off from your question, but I will make some assumptions and give you the best answer I can.

Assumption:  User has to login using some sort of credential that you are then doing a `loadUserByUsername(loginCreds)`.

If you don't want to use that specific UserDetails object, you can create an `CustomAuthenticationFilter` that is configured in your WebSecurity class by using `http.addFilterBefore(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter)`

From there, you can customize your entire authentication flow.  You can choose to create a `CustomAuthenticationToken` that in turn gets authenticated via `CustomAuthenticationProvider`.  Within this provider, you can do your password check with your 3rd party validation.  If it passes, you can load your user object as you have there.